# Retrieve choice values from lookup field in SharePoint2013

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve choice values from a lookup field in SharePoint 2013 using REST API.

PFB the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Category'",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $scope.choices=data.d.results[0].Choices.results;
         alert();
    },

            error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

This works fine for a normal choice field but doesnt work with Lookup field. Any solution?

Thanks,
Dheeraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Expand **option** to retrieve Lookup column values.

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('project')/items?$select=Client/Name,ClientId,Name,Id&$expand=Client
```

In above example, **Client** is lookup column.

Refer [this](https://www.ozkary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-2013-api-odata-for-lookup-fields.html).

Comment: can we remove duplicates from the obtained object?

Comment: Yes, take output field values in array and remove duplicate using javascript OR use jQuery.unique() using jquery. use this link for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array